# download files from list of urls

Tags: python, file, url, python-requests

I want to download from a `list` of urls the .pdf behind those urls.
This is the `list`:

```
[{'accessUrl': 'https://www.itzstedt.sitzung-online.de/bi/oparl/1.0/download.asp?dtyp=130&id=285',
  'created': '2017-11-30T12:00:00+01:00',
  'downloadUrl': None,
  'file': None,
  'fileName': '285.pdf',
  'id': 'https://www.itzstedt.sitzung-online.de/bi/oparl/1.0/files.asp?dtyp=130&id=285',
  'modified': '2017-12-06T10:34:46+01:00',
  'name': 'Vorlage-Sammeldokument',
  'reference': 'AA/2017/0001'},
 {'accessUrl': 'https://www.itzstedt.sitzung-online.de/bi/oparl/1.0/download.asp?dtyp=130&id=288',
  'created': '2017-11-30T12:00:00+01:00',
  'downloadUrl': None,
  'file': None,
  'fileName': '288.pdf',
  'id': 'https://www.itzstedt.sitzung-online.de/bi/oparl/1.0/files.asp?dtyp=130&id=288',
  'modified': '2017-11-30T17:02:39+01:00',
  'name': 'Vorlage-Sammeldokument',
  'reference': 'AA/2017/0002'},
 {'accessUrl': 'https://www.itzstedt.sitzung-online.de/bi/oparl/1.0/download.asp?dtyp=130&id=328',
  'created': '2017-11-30T12:00:00+01:00',
  'downloadUrl': None,
  'file': None,
  'fileName': '328.pdf',
  'id': 'https://www.itzstedt.sitzung-online.de/bi/oparl/1.0/files.asp?dtyp=130&id=328',
  'modified': '2017-11-30T18:23:44+01:00',
...
  'id': 'http://www.hagenbach.sitzung-online.de/bi/oparl/1.0/files.asp?dtyp=130&id=16438',
  'modified': '2017-01-04T11:22:42+01:00',
  'name': 'Vorlage-Sammeldokument',
  'reference': 'VO/2016/607'}]
```

The urls are placed in "downloadUrl"
I have wrote this code:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

for url in papers_docs:
    download_url = url.get("downloadUrl")
    if download_url:
        response = requests.get(download_url)
        file_name = url.get("fileName", os.path.basename(urlparse(download_url).path))
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f"Downloaded {file_name}")
    else:
            print(f"Failed to download {download_url}")
```

My response:

```
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
Failed to download None
```

I have tested if the data is in place with:

```
for url in papers_docs:
    download_url = url.get("downloadUrl")
    if download_url:
        print(download_url)
```

The links are in place and I can't figure the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `accessUrl` instead of `downloadUrl` because last one seems to be always `None`:

```
for url in papers_docs:
    download_url = url.get("accessUrl")
```

Comment: I have tested the 'downloadUrl' it's not always None

Comment: At least your example says something different - `'downloadUrl': None,`

Answer (score 0):

the problem accured because I haven't defined a path with:

```
os.path.basename(downloadUrl)
```

here is the correct way:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

for url in papers_docs:
    download_url = url["downloadUrl"]
    filename = url["fileName"] or os.path.basename(download_url)
    if download_url:
        response = requests.get(download_url)
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f"Downloaded {filename}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download {download_url}")
```